# Firefox keeps using cached php post sessions

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, smarty

I have a php-based admin panel of my own. I recently realized this, because I wasn't using Firefox before.

My system is a single-page app. I created it using PHP, MySQL (database), Smarty (for templates). And in the front-end JavaScript, JQuery. Also some javascript libraries such as filepond, summernote vs.

1. On my page editing section, basically when I type something, it saves the text to the database.
2. Everything is normal up to this point.
3. I go back to all pages, open a new page.
4. Type something new, then click save, but the AJAX sends the previous page's text to the server, not the one I just typed.
5. I tried this on Google Chrome, Safari and Opera as well. None of them has this kind of absurd thing.

What could be the problem? Since this is a big issue and I do not know where it could be related to I did not know which code to share.

If anyone has any idea, that would be nice.

My AJAX code:

```
$("#zPage-edit-form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var now = $("#change_lang").val();
  storingData(now);
  storeCat();

  var form = $(this).clone();
  if (form.find("select")) {
      form.find("select").each(function() {
          var name = $(this).attr("name");
          var value = $("[name='"+name+"'] option").filter(":selected").val();
          $(this).val(value);
      });
  }
  form.find("#dragulaAdd").remove();
  $("#dragula").children().each(function(i) {
      var z = $("<input>")
          .attr("name", "block"+i).val($(this).children().length-1);
      form.append(z);
  });
  form.find("input[name='filepond']").remove();
  var post_url = form.attr("action");
  var post_data = form.serialize();

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: post_url,
      data: post_data,
      success: function(responseText) {
          Toastify({
              text: responseText,
              duration: 3000
          }).showToast();
      },
      error: function(responseText) {
          Toastify({
              text: responseText,
              duration: 3000,
              backgroundColor: "#f3616d",
          }).showToast();
      },
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the ajax code? Ajax code is ran from the client, it doesn't really have anything to do with PHP sessions (PHP POST sessions aren't a thing). I'm wondering if the ajax is sending some cached client data somehow, but that would totally depend on your implementation, such as using client cookies or something.

Comment: Do you use dynamically generated elements for inputs? Do you destroy them and recreate them or are they always available on screen?

Comment: I have some things called "holders" which are like widgets, and yes, I dynamically insert them on the page, and move them around with dragula-js. Sometimes I destroy them.

Comment: Also, I just figured out, when I clear my caches, it does not do that.